# Sauver d'une / de la mort presque certaine

Tags: articles

> B. m’est venu en aide et m’a sauvé de **la** mort presque certaine.
>
> B. m’est venu en aide et m’a sauvé d'**une** mort presque certaine.

Le contexte : Les anciens amis de A. l'attaquent. B. arrive et intervient.

J'ai écrit la première phrase, puis j'ai vérifié sur Internet : il y a beaucoup plus d'exemples avec l'article indéfini.

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi employer l'article défini est une faute. À mon avis, selon le contexte, c'est l'article défini qui devrait être correct.

Answer (score 2):

1. *La mort* : La mort n'est pas qualifiée donc il n'y en a qu'une. Elle est générique.

> **Il m'a sauvé de la mort.** ✔  (comme on dit *Elle m'a donné **la** vie.*)
> <s>Il m'a sauvé d'une mort</s>. ✘ (On pourrait éventuellement le dire dans un jeu où on a plusieurs vies. De même: *elle m'a donné **une** vie.*, Ici, ***un*** est plus un nombre qu'un article)

2. *Une mort presque certaine* : On parle d'une éventualité, d'une possibilité de mourir. Elle peut se répéter.

> <s>Il m'a sauvé de la mort presque certaine</s>. ✘
> **Il m'a sauvé d'une mort presque certaine.** ✔